# Join between 3 table

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have 3 table User,HumanCustomer,CompanyCustomer
I want to join between tables with LINQ but my query is not working and its returning null

Query:

```
var query = (from users in _ctx.Users
                         join hCustomer in _ctx.HumanCustomers on users.Id equals hCustomer.UserId
                         join cCustomer in _ctx.CompanyCustomers  on users.Id equals cCustomer.UserId
                         select new
                         {
                             users.Id,
                             users.Mobile,
                             hCustomer.LastName,
                             hCustomer.Name,
                             cCustomer.CompanyName
                         });
 foreach (var item in query)
            {
                AllCustomerViewModel allCustomer = new AllCustomerViewModel();

                if (item.Name != null)
                {
                    allCustomer.UserId = item.Id;
                    allCustomer.FullName = item.Name + item.LastName;
                    allCustomer.Mobile = item.Mobile;
                    Customer.Add(allCustomer);
                }
}
```

**The code does not enter foreach**

I think the problem is using UserId twice because when I delete

```
join cCustomer in _ctx.CompanyCustomers  on users.Id equals cCustomer.UserId
```

the query runs correctly.

Comment: Not sure on data but yea, you probably need to use the user table twice, but alias with different name

Comment: How to use? @Brad

Comment: may be your CompanyCustomers table is empty, or 'UserId' column has null value. Can you check?

Comment: What happens when you write that query in sql editor? Probably some field is null and because of that result is null.

Comment: CompanyCustomers not empty @ikram

Comment: Check you data in tables, make sure that all 3 tables contain same UserId value

Comment: Can you add an expected output for the query?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your issue is the dynamic variable you are attempting to iterate over.

You could try:

```
foreach (dynamic item in query)
```

Alternatively, you write the class to hold the values you are selecting out by updating the beginning of your query to:

```
var query = (from users in _ctx.Users
                     join hCustomer in _ctx.HumanCustomers on users.Id equals hCustomer.UserId
                     join cCustomer in _ctx.CompanyCustomers  on users.Id equals cCustomer.UserId
                     select new MyClass
                     {
                         Id = users.Id,
                         Mobile = users.Mobile,
                         LastName = hCustomer.LastName,
                         Name = hCustomer.Name,
                         CompanyName = cCustomer.CompanyName
                     });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
you can try this way..

var query = (from users in _ctx.Users
                         join hCustomer in _ctx.HumanCustomers on users.Id equals hCustomer.UserId
                         join cCustomer in _ctx.CompanyCustomers  on users.Id equals cCustomer.UserId
                         select new
                         {
                             Id = users.Id,
                             Mobile = users.Mobile,
                             LastName = hCustomer.LastName,
                             Name = hCustomer.Name,
                             CompanyName = (cCustomer == null ? "" : cCustomer .CompanyName)
                         });
```

Comment: in which way does this answer helps ?